# exception handling in python for a beginner

Tags: python, exception

```
def flatten(nstd_list):
    for item in nstd_list:
        try:
            yield from flatten(item)
        except TypeError:
            yield item
```

I am a beginner for python, can you here please explain me how does this work(step by step)

Comment: Have you ever tried about reading python documentation? Once you read it, ask what you don understand.

Comment: hi thank you for your reply,I have gone  through the documentation, I am struck at the word ""yield'" here,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python

Answer (score 0):

you can take `yield` as `return`, so the code is to get every single element from a nested list.

for example:

nstd_list = [[1],2]

first round: item is [1] and 2, so `yield flatten([1])` and `2`

second round: item is 1, and return `1`